# submit a job in arm DDT

Tags: arm

I want to use the ARM DDT to profile my program (It has used MPI and CUDA) on HPC system. The super computer that I am using is PBS and for submitting the jobs I have to use the bash shells and run the command:

```
qsub job.sh
```

but I don't know how to submit the job by arm DDT application. I was wondering If you could advise me.

Comment: I've removed the tag `ddt` as it is for something else than ARM DDT.

Comment: You might get more attention from the Arm team here: https://community.arm.com/developer/tools-software/hpc/f/hpc-user-group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest (as in, least invasive) way to work with a queue is to use DDT's "reverse connect".

Firstly - load the GUI on your desktop/laptop (you don't need a licence to install this). Then, add a "remote connection" in the GUI - telling DDT where to find your supercomputer - tell it the hostname, and installation path to the tools.  Test, then connect.

On your supercomputer, login to a terminal... and where you previously might have a line like this in your qsub script:

```
./a.out
```

or like this:

```
mpirun -np 4 ./a.out
```

replace it with

```
{path-to-ddt}/bin/ddt --connect ./a.out
```

or

```
 {path-to-ddt}/bin/ddt --connect mpirun -np 4 ./a.out
```

Now, submit your job as usual - and a dialog will appear on your GUI on your laptop.  Click accept, you're now debugging.